# Fill in ArrayList with information from a couple of classes

Tags: java, oop

I'm tring to fill in an arraylist. I have three classes. First class is called Animals and it is an abstract class. There I've set two fields for age and name and an abstract method for the sound of the current animal. I've made two other classes which are called Dog and Frog. For every animal I set age, name and animal's sound (For dog BAU BAU... for example :D). The problem is that I can't fill the arraylist with information for every animal that a set. I will copy the classes here in the theme.

```
public abstract class Animals {

    public int age = 0;
    public String name = null;

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public abstract String sound();
}` 

    public class Dog extends Animals {

    public Dog(int age, String name) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String sound() {
        return ("Bau Bau" + "Kucheto e na " + this.age + " godini. I se kazva " + this.name + ".");
    }

}

    public class Frog extends Animals {

    public Frog(int age, String name) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String sound() {
        return ("Kva Kva" + "Zajabate e na " + this.age + " godini. I se kazva " + this.name + ".");
    }
}

public class Program {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Animals> animals = new ArrayList<>();
    Dog dog = new Dog(12, "Kiro");
    Frog frog = new Frog(44, "Nacho");

    animals.add(dog.sound()); here is the error ????

}
```

}

Comment: A dog sound is an animal? Why?

Comment: This line is the key to your issue, given that it's the problem statement: "The problem is that I can't fill the arraylist with information for every animal that a set." The problem I have is that I can't understand it at all. Do you mean you can't set the properties of the Dog class once you've added it to an array list?

Comment: The class `Animals` should be named `Animal`, otherwise you would get `Animals kermit = new Frog(60, "Kermit");`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to only enter types of Animals. Only the objects of Animals or objects of subclasses of Animals is a type of animal. Dog sound is not an animal.

After having all the animals in the `ArrayList` you can then loop over the `ArrayList` and call the sound method on each animal for example. If sound is indeed the method defined in the Animals class.

Answer (score 0):

dog is an object of the Dog type. Dog is a subclass of Animals. In order to add to the animals ArrayList you should call animals.add(dog). This would mean you are adding a method to the ArrayList. You are calling

```
 animals.add(dog.sound());
```

dog.sound() is a method and cannot be added to an ArrayList as only objects are added to ArrayLists.

you should call:

```
animals.add(dog);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add a `String` (the return value from `Animals.sound()`, here overridden by the `Dog` class) to a typed `ArrayList` that accepts only `Animals`. Instead,

```
animals.add(dog);
```

Answer (score -1):

With what you have written there is no point in having an Animal class. Obviously this is for a school assignment or practice assignment so you're just practicing the logic of polymorphism and abstraction... but your Animal class does nothing. It has no constructor and nothing from it is being invoked from what I can see. It may as well be an Interface instead which would then force all classes that implement it to have the sound() method.

Are you sure you don't want Animal class to do anything? Also, age and name should most likely be private or protected.